# Swagger response description not shown

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I am currently attempting to display a description of a particular response in Swagger UI, but there doesn't seem to be a documentation that truly covers all aspects of that, and all the examples I've tried from [Get started with Swashbuckle and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) don't work in .NET Core 3.1...

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Test route...
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// <response code="200">This is a test</response>
        [HttpGet]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok("Hello World");
        }
```

My .csproj contains the following as well:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

The Swagger UI ends up looking like this (and as you can see, the "Descriptipn" column doesn't contain the "This is a test" text as it probably should). Am I missing something?

[image: Image preview]

I also had added `[SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status200OK, ...)]` to it, but nothing changes.

Comment: Did you add  <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile> to your .csproj file? And the startup code so swagger can find the generated files? Check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#xml-comments

Comment: @erikbozic Yes, I did. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add example responses in Swagger in a ASP .NET minimal API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76272321/how-to-add-example-responses-in-swagger-in-a-asp-net-minimal-api)

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim The question has already been answered.

Comment: Sorry for the automatically created unintentional question - the comment should be read as  [“Possible duplicate”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339563/the-auto-comment-does-this-answer-your-question-generated-when-voting-to-clos)

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry. Though, I believe this should be the answer to the other question, since mine is much older. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As it turns out, `[SwaggerResponse]` works properly, but before, I need to "enable annotations" in my Startup...

```cs
    services.AddSwaggerGen(config =>
    {
        config.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Title = "Some API",
            Version = "v1"
        });

        config.EnableAnnotations();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this!  I was cursing Swagger for having a bug and thought I would have to use the XML documentation.

Comment: Note that you need to install the [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckleaspnetcoreannotations) NuGet package.

Answer (score 9):

Since .NET v6 there're two ways of managing the API: [classic API controllers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api#scaffold-a-controller) and [minimal API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis). They're quite different, so I provide two answers below.

**For the classic/traditional API controllers**

As per the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?#describe-response-types), it's done via XML comment with a combination of `ProducesResponseType` attribute:

```
<response code="201">This is a test</response>
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
```

The comments need to be linked to Swagger

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    // using System.Reflection;
    var xmlFilename = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFilename));
});
```

**For the minimal API**

In .NET 6, the minimal API is quite raw, with patchy support from both NSwag and Swashbuckle.
It only supports the old-school attributes (as per [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72103406/968003)):

```
app.MapGet("/clients",
    [SwaggerOperation(
        Summary = "returns clients",
        Description = "more description on get `clients`")]
    [SwaggerResponse(200, "success")]
    [SwaggerResponse(500, "some failure")]
    async (IClientRepository repo) =>
    {
        var results = await repo.GetClientsAsync();
        return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ClientModel>>(results);
    }).WithTags("Clients");
```

.NET 7 has several useful extension methods added. One of them is [Produces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.openapiroutehandlerbuilderextensions.produces) that provides the type and HTTP code but lacks a handy message:

```
app.MapGet("/clients",
    async (IClientRepository repo) =>
    {
        var results = await repo.GetClientsAsync();
        return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ClientModel>>(results);
    }).Produces<IEnumerable<ClientModel>>(StatusCodes.Status200OK)
      .WithTags("Clients")
      .WithSummary("returns clients")
      .WithDescription("more description on get `clients`");
```

The advantage of using those extension methods is that you can apply them in bulk, for example:

```
var routes = new[] { 
    app.MapGet("/clients", (IClientRepository repo) => repo.GetClients()),
    app.MapGet("/users", (IUserRepository repo) => repo.GetUsers()),
};
foreach (var route in routes)                               
    route.WithTags("Lists");
```

Comment: I needed to use this one in my .net6 API

Answer (score 2):

In your project properties you should check `Output XML documentation file` found under the blade `Build`. Then in your `startup` file:

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    //rest of your code

    //i'm using the default path generated, but you can adjust it as you want
    var XMLPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + nameof(MyNamespace) + ".xml";
    if (File.Exists(XMLPath))
    {
        c.IncludeXmlComments(XMLPath);
    }
});
```

If that still doesn't work check if the xml file appears in the `bin` folder. If not check the properties within Visual Studio and adjust `Copy to output directory` to `Copy` or `Copy if newer`.