# Add Swagger description to minimal .NET 6 APIs

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui, .net-6.0, minimal-apis

I have a small project in .NET 6 that contains minimal APIs like that one

```cs
app.MapGet("/clients",
     async (IClientRepository repo) =>
     {
          var results = await repo.GetClientsAsync();
          return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ClientModel>>(results);
     });
```

In the `SwaggerUI` I can use this API but I can't find a way to add description to it (although in the project settings I check for creating an API XML documentation).

[image]

How can I add the XML comment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add example responses in Swagger in a ASP .NET minimal API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76272321/how-to-add-example-responses-in-swagger-in-a-asp-net-minimal-api)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**1. Install package**

```
dotnet add package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations
```

**2. Write code**

```cs
// Program.cs

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(x =>
{
  x.EnableAnnotations();
});

// app.MapGet("/hi", [SwaggerOperation(Summary = "summary001", Description = "description001 `adads`")] () => "Hi");

app.MapGet("/hi", () => "Hi")
  .WithMetadata(new SwaggerOperationAttribute("summary001", "description001"));
```

## Result

[image]

Answer (score 31):

Currently support for Open API docs for minimal APIs is [quite minimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#openapi) and does not allow adding descriptions/summaries as far as I can see. There is a feature planned for [.NET 7](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37906) to add descriptions. Also soon `Swashbuckle` should [consider `EndpointMetadata` for annotations](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/pull/2215).

Also related [issue](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/2267).

**UPDATE**

With latest updates to `Swashbuckle` nuget packages and `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations` you can add description to the endpoints:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(opts => opts.EnableAnnotations());

app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", () =>
{
    // Implementation
})
.WithMetadata(new SwaggerOperationAttribute(summary: "Summary", description: "Descritption Test"));

// Or

app.MapGet("/weatherforecast1", [SwaggerOperation(summary: "Summary1", description: "Descritption Test1")] () =>
{
    // Implementation
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

For .NET 7 and latest `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` package `WithDescription` method also can be used:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
...

app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", () =>
{
    // implementation
})
.WithDescription("Some Method Description")
.WithOpenApi();
```

Or with `EndpointDescriptionAttribute`:

```cs
app.MapGet("/weatherforecast1", [EndpointDescription("Some Attribute description")] () =>
{
    // implementation
})
.WithOpenApi();
```

Comment: I would like to add, that ``WithOpenApi`` method you can find in [Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi/) NuGet package.

Comment: The `WithOpenApi` extension method also supports setting the operation's description by passing a delegate like `operation => operation.Description = "foo"; return operation;`. It's a little bit more robust because you can modify the entire operation.

Comment: While some of the provided solutions work for pieces of documentation (like summary and description), I can't seem to find any information on documenting parameters. Has anyone come across the appropriate way to add documentation for the parameters?

Comment: @Xorcist AFAIK .NET 7 should support swagger documentation from xml comments - you can try it. Or try marking parameters with `SwaggerParameterAttribute` from `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations`.

Comment: I found the route cause of the parameters not be documented (in my case). Turns out if the minimal api endpoint mapping is defined with .WithOpenApi() the parameters will not be processed, but if you take that method call off, everything works as expected.

Comment: Support XML-based OpenAPI docs for minimal APIs
#39927 https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39927  Is not in .Net 8 planning yet.

Answer (score 15):

package `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations` `6.3`

```
...
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c => c.EnableAnnotations());

var app = builder.build();

app.MapGet("/clients",
    [SwaggerOperation(
        Summary = "returns clients",
        Description = "more description on get `clients`")]
    [SwaggerResponse(200, "success")]
    [SwaggerResponse(500, "some failure")]
    async (IClientRepository repo) =>
    {
        var results = await repo.GetClientsAsync();
        return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ClientModel>>(results);
    }).WithTags("Clients");
```

more examples here
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#enrich-operation-metadata

Answer (score 2):

you may use Extension Methods Which I think are more cleaner way to document API endpoints. This way you can define generic response methods for each endpoint.

For this you need to install the following packages :

[Swashbuckle.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen/) and [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations;


public static class MinimalAttributeExtensions
{
    public static RouteHandlerBuilder AllowAnonymous(this RouteHandlerBuilder endpoint)
    {
        endpoint.WithMetadata(new AllowAnonymousAttribute());
        return endpoint;
    }
    public static RouteHandlerBuilder Authorize(this RouteHandlerBuilder endpoint, string policy = null, string[] roles = null, params string[] schemes)
    {
        var authorizeAttribute = new AuthorizeAttribute();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy))
        {
            authorizeAttribute.Policy = policy;
        }

        if (roles != null && roles.Any())
        {
            authorizeAttribute.Roles = string.Join(',', roles);
        }

        if (schemes != null && schemes.Any())
        {
            authorizeAttribute.AuthenticationSchemes = string.Join(',', schemes);
        }

        endpoint.WithMetadata(authorizeAttribute);

        return endpoint;
    }
    public static RouteHandlerBuilder AddMetaData<T>(this RouteHandlerBuilder endpoint, string tag, string summary = null, string description = null)
    {
        endpoint.WithTags(tag);

        endpoint.WithMetadata(new SwaggerOperationAttribute(summary, description));

        endpoint.WithMetadata(new SwaggerResponseAttribute(200, type: typeof(T)))
                .WithMetadata(new SwaggerResponseAttribute(500, type: typeof(ErrorResponseModel)))
                .WithMetadata(new SwaggerResponseAttribute(400, type: typeof(ErrorResponseModel)))
                .WithMetadata(new SwaggerResponseAttribute(404, type: typeof(ErrorResponseModel)))
                .WithMetadata(new SwaggerResponseAttribute(422, type: typeof(ErrorResponseModel)))
                .WithMetadata(new SwaggerResponseAttribute(304, type: typeof(ErrorResponseModel)));

        return endpoint;
    }
    public static RouteHandlerBuilder AddMetaData(this RouteHandlerBuilder endpoint, string tag, string summary = null, string description = null)
    {
        endpoint.WithTags(tag);

        endpoint.WithMetadata(new SwaggerOperationAttribute(summary, description));

        endpoint.WithMetadata(new SwaggerResponseAttribute(500, type: typeof(ErrorResponseModel)))
                .WithMetadata(new SwaggerResponseAttribute(400, type: typeof(ErrorResponseModel)))
                .WithMetadata(new SwaggerResponseAttribute(404, type: typeof(ErrorResponseModel)))
                .WithMetadata(new SwaggerResponseAttribute(422, type: typeof(ErrorResponseModel)))
                .WithMetadata(new SwaggerResponseAttribute(304, type: typeof(ErrorResponseModel)));

        return endpoint;
    }
}
```

following is an example of how to use these extension Methods:

```
app.MapGet(“/books”, async (BooksDB db) =>
{
    return await db.Books.ToListAsync()
})
.Authorize(policy : "AdminOnly", roles : new string[] {1,2}, schemes: "Bearer")
.AddMetaData<List<Book>>
(
    tag : "Books",
    summary : "Get All Books",
    description : "Get All Books in List, Roles Allowed => Admin Only"
);
```

The `.AddMetaData<T>` here represents the response model for success, this will also add to the response documentation of this endpoint. In this case it is `List<Book>`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [this guide](https://medium.com/geekculture/minimal-apis-in-net-6-a-complete-guide-beginners-advanced-fd64f4da07f5). It worked for me using Swashbuckle. There are extension methods that come with minimal APIs. Here is how it looks:

```
app.MapGet(“/books”, async (BooksDB db) =>
await db.Books.ToListAsync()
)
.Produces<List<Book>>(StatusCodes.Status200OK)
.WithName(“GetAllBooks”).WithTags(“Getters”);
```

Comment: This link doesn't explain how to add a comment